# how do i get a new number to generate

Tags: javascript, while-loop

i need to make a dice rolling program that rolls dice and says who won if it is a tie it rolls again and after each win you earn a point first to 5 wins the game whenever i run mine it uses the same numbers over and over again because it only generated the once how can i fix this and what else do i need to do after this issue to finish the program, thanks for the help!

```
    <script>

var comp1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1);
var comp2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1);
var you1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1);
var you2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1);
var counter = 1;
var youPoints = 0;
var mePoints = 0;


while(counter < 6)
{{
    alert("Let's shake some dice!")

alert("your turn to roll \n\n you shook a " + you1 + " and a " +  you2 + ", so you have " + (you1 + you2));

    alert("my turn to roll \n\n I shook a " + comp1 + " and a " +  comp2 + ", so I have " + (comp1 + comp2));
    counter++

    var you = you1 + you2;
    var me = comp1 + comp2;
    if(you > me)
    {
        alert("you win " + you + " to " + me);
        youPoints++
    }
    if (me > you)
    {

        alert("I win " + me + " to " + you);
        mePoints++

    }


}}




</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're initializing your random variables (`you1, you2`) outside the while loop.

It's being initialized only once and hence producing the same number every time.

Bring it inside the loop, and that might fix it!

Answer (score -1):

Move the code the generates the random numbers to inside of the loop because, right now, they only generate once... before the loop even starts.

Also, do yourself a favor and use a `for` counting loop, rather than a `while`, because `while` loops are easily misconfigured to cause infinite loops to occur.

```js
var youPoints = 0;
var mePoints = 0;

for(var counter = 1; counter < 6; counter++){
  // The code that generates the random numbers has to be in the loop
  // in order for new randoms to be generated upon each loop iteration
  var comp1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1);
  var comp2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1);
  var you1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1);
  var you2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1);
  
  alert("Let's shake some dice!")
  alert("your turn to roll \n\n you shook a " + you1 + " and a " +  you2 + ", so you have " + (you1 + you2));
  alert("my turn to roll \n\n I shook a " + comp1 + " and a " +  comp2 + ", so I have " + (comp1 + comp2));

  var you = you1 + you2;
  var me = comp1 + comp2;
  
  // Don't make two separate if statements. Use one with an else if
  if(you > me) {
    alert("you win " + you + " to " + me);
    youPoints++
  } else if (me > you) {
    alert("I win " + me + " to " + you);
    mePoints++
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go, this should be a complete working example.

**Note:** I replaced `alert()` for `console.log()` so we can see the output here in the console and without popups, but it will work either way.

```js
var compPoints = 0;
var youPoints = 0;
var winnerOfFive = false;

function rollTheDice() {
  return Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1);
}

function rollAllDice() {
  let you1 = rollTheDice();
  let you2 = rollTheDice();
  let comp1 = rollTheDice();
  let comp2 = rollTheDice();

  console.log("your turn to roll \n\n you shook a " + you1 + " and a " +  you2 + ", so you have " + (you1 + you2));
  console.log("my turn to roll \n\n I shook a " + comp1 + " and a " +  comp2 + ", so I have " + (comp1 + comp2));

  var you = you1 + you2;
  var me = comp1 + comp2;

  if(you > me) {
    console.log("you win " + you + " to " + me);
    youPoints++;
  } else if(me > you) {
    console.log("I win " + me + " to " + you);
    compPoints++;
  } else {
    console.log("It was a tie, no one wins. Re-rolling...");
    rollAllDice();
  }
}

function startGame() {
  while( !winnerOfFive ) {
    console.log("Let's shake some dice!")
    rollAllDice();

    if(compPoints == 5) {
      console.log("Comp is first to 5 games and wins " + compPoints + " to " + youPoints);
      winnerOfFive = true;
    } else if (youPoints == 5) {
      console.log("You are first to 5 games and win " + youPoints + " to " + compPoints);
      winnerOfFive = true;
    }
  }
}

// Start the game like this
startGame();
```